# string to stream in java without bytearrayinputstream

Tags: java

How to convert string to stream in java without using bytearrayinputstream and example?

Comment: you can try: InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(IOUtils.toInputStream(myString));

Comment: What's wrong with 'bytearrayinputstream'?

Comment: Do you need to copy a stream of a string to an OutputStream? If so, you can use commons IOUtils.copy(new StringReader(someString), someOutputStream);

Comment: @Nikita Rybak My thoughts exactly.

Comment: Harry, the toInputStream(String) still uses ByteArrayInputStream: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toInputStream(String)

Comment: @biziclop - that's what comment upvotes are for :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could extend the `InputStream` class and implement the `read()` method such that it returns data from a String.

But it would be really useless to do that when using a `ByteArrayInputStream` is so much simpler and easier.

Comment: I thought this might be a J2ME thing, but ByteArrayInputStream is part of the the profiles. Perhaps this is just a lame interview question ...

Comment: perhaps it is a memory concern?

Answer (score 0):

InputStream is = new StringInputStream(string);

Comment: Or `new StringReader(string)` if you actually want a Reader.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-1996/javadev/classes/doc/java.io.StringInputStream.html

Comment: @nIKUNJ: take a look at the actual current API doc. You will not find that class. It seems to have been from a beta version of Java 1.0 and dropped before the final release. Look at the date in the URL...